# Add OpenSSL library to vc project

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, openssl, sha256

i download the library openssl (LAtest) from [here](https://www.openssl.org/source). 
I create a new empty project and i add the existing item sha256t.c to my project. But i can't add library openssl to my project to work perfectly. I would like to know the steps can i folow to do it.
I am using visual studio 2013 and windows 7 operating system.

Comment: You want to build the OpenSSL library form source, or you want to build your own project using a ready compiled version of the OpenSSL library?

Comment: i want to build the OpenSSL library.I have a file with some interger value and I just want to have the hash of this value using sha 256